# amazon ec2 ip whitelisted on a third party service provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently we are running an application in a single amazon ec2 machine. On our application we are using some third party
solution. For using those solution, we have asked the third party service provider to whitelist our ec2 machine ip.

```
our EC2 machine: IP - 172.12.32.55
Third party solution like global.bank.com and we have told global.bank.com to whitelist our IP
```

Now we want to scale up our application. 
We are planing to setup multiple node (our application in multiple ec2 machine) and a load balancer.

So my questions is, how i can manage our third party solution provider? Should I give all our ec2 machine ips to 
our third party solution providers for whitelist? Or is their any other solution to handle the situation?

Comment: Will your EC2 instances be in private subnet and use NAT gateway? Then you can provide IP associated with Elastic IP attached to the gateway.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. i'm not clear about amazon networking. i'm just creating a vpc and attach a elastic ip.

Comment: Elastic IP is fine for small number of instances. You can only use 5 EIPs per region.  Thus, if you want to scale out, as you wrote, probably have to think about more manageable and scalable solution, not limited by 5 EIPs.

Comment: Currently we have only one EC2 machine and we have added one elastic IP on that machine. We are going create a new EC2 machine and add this machine to a VPC (those 2 machines are now on the same VPC). Now, is it okay only to make the previous elastic IP whitelisted?

Comment: The two machines will have 2 EIPs? Thus I think you have to whitelist both IPs? If you whitelist only one IP, one instance will have access to your provider, second will not.

Comment: And if we use a load-balancer, then those ec2 machine ip attached with the load balancer and ip of load balancer goes to the third party provider. am i right ?

Comment: Not quite right. The LB is used for connections to your instances, not for connections going out. Since your instances connect to the third party, they connect directly - not using LB. But if you have them in private subnet, they will have to go through NAT gateway. The NAT gateway has one EIP. This EIP will be used by all instances that use the gateway that want to connect to internet. Since its private subnet, direct connection to your instances from internet will not be possible though, unlike in public subnet.